# Concern with Display small Number in ExtJS Chart

Tags: extjs

Extjs Version : 6.6.0
We have used an ExtJs horizontal chart bar chart view to show our data.

Our concern is in a chart, we display three categories of Recordset,

```
Completed Count
Error Count
Pending Count
```

Now it has data like,

```
Completed = 2000  
Error = 1  
Pending = 0
```

In Chart there is no line or indication for this error = 1 count, can someone help us on how to show this small number in the chart?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Viral, hello here - would please share more code or better a fiddle?

Comment: This is a common problem with charting with large range of values.  It is not really a sencha or extjs issue.   You can change the scale of your data or choose a different chart  type that will highlight the differences.  https://peltiertech.com/chart-a-wide-range-of-values/

Comment: Thanks for the update if it common issue I can check for different chart type,